# Unrecognised selector sent to instance on calling any variable from other controller.

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, unrecognized-selector

I have a ViewController CafeViewController namely. It contains many global arrays and variables, Im trying to call its one of the variable in my other view controller reservationViewController namely via following lines of code

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
CafesViewController *controller2 = (CafesViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

NSLog(@"title which is in next screen is %@", controller2.restuarentsList);
```

Now I have checked with the help of breakpoint that there is no error before NSLog, after putting nslog line of code it gets terminated. Help please

warning is :- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController restuarentsList]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a3d9320'

Comment: Please check "CafesViewController" is your initial view controller or not in the storyboard?

Comment: It is neither my initial view controller nor its absent from storyboard.

Comment: Your initial view controller is a navigation controller and not your CafesViewController.

Comment: yes exactly! cafeViewController is not my initial viewController

Comment: If `cafeViewController` isn't your `initialViewController` why do you cast the view controller which is returned from `instantiateInitialViewController` which will be your initial view (Its in the name) to `cafeViewController`? I think what you are after is `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check `CafesViewController` is initial viewcontroller in storyboard. If it is not, then instantiate it with the following code:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
CafesViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CafesViewController"];
```

And also, keep in mind to set the identifier of the ViewController in storyboard as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Okay let me try your code! and the name of my storyboard is Main.Storyboard so I'm changing it from @"MainStroryboard" to @"Main"

Comment: set the identifier of the ViewController in storyboard.